# Use Javascript to refresh a window after a loop has run its course

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, page-refresh

I'm writing a news display for the company I work at and I'm trying to get the page to refresh after it's looped through the entire length of a JSON array. Currently everything works, but I'm not entirely sure where the refresh command would go. Where it is at the moment is not executing. Here's my relevant code:

```js
var i = 0,
    d = null,
    x = null,
    interval = 3000;

    console.log('welcome');

    $(document).ready(function(){
      fetch();
      console.log('fetching');
    });

    function fetch(){
      // get the data *once* when the page loads
      $.getJSON('info.json?ver=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), function(data){
        // store the data in a global variable 'd'
        d = data[0];
        console.log('results');
        console.log(data);
        // create a recurring call to update()
        x = setInterval(function(){
          update()
        }, interval);
      });
    }

    function update(){
      console.log('update starting');
      // if there isn't an array element, reset to the first once
      if (d && !d[i]){
        console.log('got the D');
        clearInterval(x);
        i = 0;
        fetch();
        return;
        if(d[i] >= d.length){
          // refresh the window if the variable is longer than the array
          console.log('refreshing');
          window.location.reload();
        }
      }
      // remove the previous items from the page
      $('ul').empty();
      // add the next item to the page
      $('ul').append(
        '<li>' + d[i]['news']
        + '</li>'
      );
      // increment for the next iteration
      i++;

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='news'>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `if(d[i] >= d.length){` should probably be `if(i >= d.length){`

Comment: The first thing I can see that there is a return statement followed by code in the same block (in the update function after fetch). So return is stoping executing the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out going in a direction I wasn't originally planning to.  I realized that once I included an RNG for version control to my .json file I actually didn't need to refresh the page.  I am using an iterative loop, so once the loop completes it goes back to the top, and re-opens the `info.json`.  My RNG looks like this:

```
$.getJSON('info.json?ver=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '.' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), function(data){
//code here
}
```

This means that every time `$.getJSON` is caled, it's looking at a different version number than it was before, which forces a server check and download, which keeps things in the file updating to the screen on their own.  Network sources looked like this:

```
info.json?ver=1.23
info.json?ver=2.42
info.json?ver=1.15
```

Definitely not the solution I was looking for, but it is actually a better solution than my question could have asked.

Comment: Just a suggestion- instead of using a random number, you could use a timestamp; something like `'info.json?t=' + Date.now()`. That way the number will always be unique. Using a random number has a chance (albeit minimal since you're using two) of using the same number twice, thus pulling a cached copy of the JSON file. Or, set the server to send out a no-cache header for JSON files in the directory. As regards reloading, something like `if(i >= d.length) { window.location.reload(); }` just after incrementing the `i` in `update` might work, but that won't guarantee JSON pulled from the server.

Comment: You're right, and I've updated my code to use this instead.  I figure grabbing a random timestamp will be better than asking the broswer to do math twice.  Also with an eternally unique number things will go a bit better in the refresh.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('info.json?ver=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), function(data){
    //your code
}).done(function( data ) {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Function written in done section will be executed after complete all code from main function

Comment: the placement of the `.done(function(data){` function is causing the page to refresh immediately without executing the update() function to loop through the array.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you question, you just need to know where your reload function is correct?

Well it's `window.location.reload();`

Comment: I worded it wrong.  I need to know where it would go to have the page refresh after the loop has run its course.  Currently the `window.location.reload()` command isn't executing at all.  I want it to reload when the array has been looped through